# Backbone Collection

Tags: django, backbone.js

I was trying to make a Backbone Application with Django at its backend. I was following a Backbone tutorial. I used the following code:

**Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>IstreetApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Book Manager</h1>
        <hr />
        <div class="page"></div>
    </div>

    <script type = "text/template" id = "booklist.template">

    </script>

    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.10/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
            options.url = 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com' + options.url;
        });

        var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: '/books'
        });

        var BookList = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '.page',
            render: function () {
                var that = this;
                var books = new Books();
                books.fetch({
                    success: function(books) {
                        var template = _.template($('#booklist.template').html(), {books: books.models});
                        that.$el.html(template);
                    }
                })
            }
        });

        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                '': 'home'
            }
        })

        var bookList = new BookList();

        var router = new Router();
        router.on('route:home', function () {
            bookList.render();
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Since the collection is not defined, the success code doesn't execute. I suppose the collection data should come from the server through Django but I am not sure how and in what form. Kindly help. I am pretty much new to backbone and Django.

Comment: Why don't you put an error handler on your _fetch_ call?

Comment: @svetoslavnedkov how can i do that?

Comment: it uses the same format as the success handler, just put ',error: function (data) {alert(data);}' after your sucess handler.

Comment: It doesn't alert me with any error. I haven't asked server to send the data while fetching the `index` template. Should I do that?

Comment: Actually I tried the code you have and what I get is a 404 from the server, so the problem I think is server side. You must put in place a request handler that returns books for GET requests for /books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call fetch on your collection, it makes an AJAX request to:

```
 http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/books
```

However, there is no API set up there.  Either one of two things needs to happen:

1) you need to modify your code to point to a different URL, one that does have an existing API (perhaps whatever tutorial you are using has such an API)

2) you need to create such an API yourself on yoursever.com (and then make your Backbone code point to that API's URL instead)

Without a server to support it, operations like `save` and `fetch` and such in Backbone simply cannot function.

As a side note, Django is a web *site* framework.  While you can use it to create server-side *APIs*, that's not really Django's focus.  Because of this, several good third party libraries exist for doing RESTful APIs (ie. the kind that Backbone likes) in Django; personally I'd recommend either Django REST Framework (I use it and it works great) or TastyPie (never used it, but it's very popular).

Comment: That makes sense. I was waiting for such answer. Can pystache(Mustache) be used for the same purpose?

Comment: You *could*, but it'd be a bad idea.  What I mean is, you can use a templating system (either pystache or Django's) to make a JSON response, with a template that's something like: `{id: {{id}}, someField: {{valueOfSomeField}}, someString: '{someStringValue}}'}` and a Django View that provides those values. However that gets ugly fast.  Building the JSON in the View instead (with TastyPie/Django REST Framework), will almost work better; for example `response = JSONResponse(); response.id = id; response.someField = someField; response.someString = someStringValue; return response;`.

Comment: P.S. I know semi-colons are not very Pythonic, but comments don't support newlines, so ...

Comment: Thanks alot. I am using Django REST Framework and its really good.

Comment: Glad I could help.  BTW, for any future readers I meant to say "will almost *certainly* work better" in my previous comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

When using a backbone collection you need to return a json array of objects from your api url (http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/books)
Example

```
{[{"name":"bookname", "publisher": "penguin"}, {"name":"bookname", "publisher":"penguin"}]}
```

You'll also want a model for your collection. A model would look like this 
Example:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
"name":  "",
"publisher": ""
}
});
```

The way that the collection works is by parsing the json array and turning each object in the array in to a model that you specific (in this instant an individual book with values for the name and publisher).

When you make a .fetch() on your model you are making a GET request, so make sure that your http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/books url is prepared to receive GET requests and respond with the json data in the format I specified up top.